# Microsoft OLE DB Service Components error 8007007E

Tags: ado, delphi-xe8, interbase

My **Delphi XE8** app `MyApp.exe` fails with EOleException

```
ErrorCode = -2147024770 {$8007007E}, 
Message = 'The specified module could not be found'
Source = 'Microsoft OLE DB Service Components'
```

which unfortunately doesn't give name of the incriminated module.

The exception is raised during the very first attempt to access **Interbase XE7** via **ADO** and **IBProvider**, using ConnectionString

```
Provider=LCPI.IBProvider.3.Lite;
Password=masterkey;
Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=SYSDBA;
Data Source=AFGIR;
Location=localhost/IBXE7D:E:\DvpData\Test.ADO\IB_XE7\AFGIRG7.IBXE7;
ctype=UTF8;
ctype_user=ACP;
dialect=3;
auto_commit=True;
dbclient_library="C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\IBXE7D\bin\gds32.dll";
```

The same ConnectionString without `dbclient_library` property (i.e. with default client library) leads to the same error.

The modules present in memory just before and just after IB access attempt are the same (according to **Process Explorer**), namely:

```
advapi32.dll    Advanced Windows 32 Base API    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll
apisetschema.dll    ApiSet Schema DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\apisetschema.dll
atl.dll ATL Module for Windows XP (Unicode) Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atl.dll
bcrypt.dll  Windows Cryptographic Primitives Library (Wow64)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll
bcryptprimitives.dll    Windows Cryptographic Primitives Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll
clbcatq.dll COM+ Configuration Catalog  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll
comctl32.dll    User Experience Controls Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll
comctl32.dll    User Experience Controls Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
comctl32.dll.mui    Common Controls Library Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.c..-controls.resources_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16385_en-us_020378a8991bbcc2\comctl32.dll.mui
comdlg32.dll    Common Dialogs DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll
comsvcs.dll COM+ Services   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comsvcs.dll
cryptbase.dll   Base cryptographic API DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll
cryptsp.dll Cryptographic Service Provider API  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll
dwmapi.dll  Microsoft Desktop Window Manager API    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll
gdi32.dll   GDI Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll
GdiPlus.dll Microsoft GDI+  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17514_none_72d18a4386696c80\GdiPlus.dll
MyApp.exe   MyApplication(Srv)  MyCompany   E:\Dvp\Delphi16\MyAppSrv\MyApp.exe
imm32.dll   Multi-User Windows IMM32 API Client DLL Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll
kernel32.dll    Windows NT BASE API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
kernel32.dll.mui    Windows NT BASE API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\en-US\kernel32.dll.mui
KernelBase.dll  Windows NT BASE API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
KernelBase.dll.mui  Windows NT BASE API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\en-US\KernelBase.dll.mui
locale.nls          C:\Windows\System32\locale.nls
lpk.dll Language Pack   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll
mpr.dll Multiple Provider Router DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll
msado15.dll ActiveX Data Objects    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll
msctf.dll   MSCTF Server DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll
msdart.dll  OLE DB Runtime Routines Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msdart.dll
msvcrt.dll  Windows NT CRT DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
ntdll.dll   NT Layer DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
ntdll.dll   NT Layer DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
ole32.dll   Microsoft OLE for Windows   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll
oleaut32.dll        Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll
oledb32.dll OLE DB Core Services    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll
oledb32r.dll    OLE DB Core Services Resources  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32r.dll
oledb32r.dll.mui    OLE DB Core Services Resources  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\en-US\oledb32r.dll.mui
riched20.dll    Rich Text Edit Control, v3.1    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\riched20.dll
rpcrt4.dll  Remote Procedure Call Runtime   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll
RpcRtRemote.dll Remote RPC Extension    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll
rsaenh.dll  Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll
sechost.dll Host for SCM/SDDL/LSA Lookup APIs   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
shell32.dll Windows Shell Common Dll    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll
shlwapi.dll Shell Light-weight Utility Library  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll
SortDefault.nls         C:\Windows\Globalization\Sorting\SortDefault.nls
sspicli.dll Security Support Provider Interface Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll
StaticCache.dat         C:\Windows\Fonts\StaticCache.dat
user32.dll  Multi-User Windows USER API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll
usp10.dll   Uniscribe Unicode script processor  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll
uxtheme.dll Microsoft UxTheme Library   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
version.dll Version Checking and File Installation Libraries    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll
winspool.drv    Windows Spooler Driver  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv
winsta.dll  Winstation Library  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winsta.dll
wow64.dll   Win32 Emulation on NT64 Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll
wow64cpu.dll    AMD64 Wow64 CPU     Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll
wow64win.dll    Wow64 Console and Win32 API Logging Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\wow64win.dll
wtsapi32.dll    Windows Remote Desktop Session Host Server SDK APIs Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wtsapi32.dll
```

MyApp.exe worked fine 3 weeks ago. Nothing, as far as I remember, was changed in the source since. I suspect rather a "collateral" incoherence of the system. Meanwhile, **System File Checker** finds no coherence violation and **DependencyWalker** don't give me any pertinent (for me) indication.

Q1. Have you any idea how to pinpoint the error cause?

Q2. Does there exist list of **all** DLLs related to Microsoft OLE DB Service Components, or better, a program checking their coherent presence on a system?

Kind regards,
JK

Comment: Have you tried doing a TDump on your gds32.dll?

Comment: @MartynA. If you mean: "check presence on disk of all DLLs that gds32.dll needs (imports)", the answer is "Yes, I did that just now with TDump". Before, I used DependencyWalker. I am novice to so system-deep investigations. I wonder why the exception doesn't give name of the lacking module? Could API hooking help zooming on the error origin?